# affect a variable list to weights/biases lstm tensorflow

Tags: parameters, tensorflow, lstm

I'm beginner in tensorflow, and I knew that the  function `tf.global_variables_initializer()` adds an op to initialize all variables in the model. You can also pass an explicit list of variables to initialize to `tf.variables_initializer`, so how can I do it.

In fact I turned this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/6_lstm.ipynb) after training step I'd like to pass to test step with my own list of weights/biases which are defined in a simple variable x, any one can help me

Comment: to more explicate my problem, I used this code to have the dimension of trainable variables: ` total_parameters = 0
    v1=session.run(tf.trainable_variables())
   
  for variable in tf.trainable_variables():
    v=session.run(tf.trainable_variables())
   
    # shape is an array of tf.Dimension
    shape = variable.get_shape()
        variable_parametes = 1
    for dim in shape:
       variable_parametes *= dim.value
       total_parameters += variable_parametes`

Comment: after that I create a variable x with  dimension of trainable variable. x is filled by the best parameters, so haw can I affect those best values to our trainable variables,

please is there any idea ?? thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. My best guess is that you want to override your weights sometime into training. Am I correct?

Comment: fistly thanks @cleros for your response, yes I want to override all weights. in tensorflow code we initialize weights by randomly values, after that weights are updated by gradient, in this point I want to override this weights by my one list, I tried this: 'for variable in sess.run(tf.trainable_variables()):
             variable=x'

Comment: That will not work. Have a look at tf.assign: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign

Comment: import tensorflow as tf
weight = tf.Variable(0)
y = tf.assign(weight, my_list)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(x)
    print sess.run(y)     ''''but my_list is defined after running the session

Comment: To perform the assign op while outside of the computation graph, you can do `sess.run(tf.assign(variable, value))` (don't do it in a loop, though, since you'll generate an op at each iteration). If inside of your graph, look into https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies .